# Creating SMS Gateway or using 3rd party

Tags: sms-gateway

Hi i am building a website which needs to send sms.
Scenario is User will create his/her account using his/her mobile no.
After that he can send sms through website to any mobile number.
When the end user receive the sms the sender no should be the same the number with which he registered.
I want to code it in C#

Answer (score 1):

The similar thing has been done and the code has been released for a 3rd party SMS Gateway called Way2SMS here at Code Globe. http://www.codeglobe.in/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=30&Itemid=36

Comment: and the receiver will see the sender's number?

Comment: Since you are using Way2SMS gateway, the receiver will see only the sender's number. That service is provided by Way2SMS. You do not have to do anything for that to happen.

Comment: what Way2sms used to send sms? Any idea

Comment: Way2sms is a free SMS sending website. Check it out at [link](www.way2sms.com). Try to send messages from it and if you think that's what you are looking for then implement the API from the link given above.